# Create a buffer and work on it

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Is it possible to create a buffer of arbitrary size and work on that just like on a canvas element?

I would like to create a graphic (> 10'000 x 10'000 pixel) and use methods like `drawImage()` on that. After everything is done a part should be copied over to the canvas element.
`createImageData()` can make a buffer but there's no way to use methods like `drawImage()` on it.

Is there a way to achieve my needs without making an invisible canvas element?

Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why not use a canvas element? It doesn't have to be "invisible" (as in "it's part of the page, but styled to not be visible")...just create a new canvas as described above, and simply don't append it to your document. Now you can do whatever you want with it, without worrying about having that extra hidden canvas on your actual page.

Comment: I'm not sure what is meant by "as described above", but the @David_Murdoch answer demonstrates how to create a new canvas which is not in the displayed document: `var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");`

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at document fragments. [John Resig DOM DocumentFragments](http://ejohn.org/blog/dom-documentfragments/) and [MDC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/DocumentFragment).

I'm not sure if it is cross-browser...maybe someone can clarify for me?

---

EDIT: don't know what I was thinking

Have you tried:

```
var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
canvas....

containerElement.appendChild(canvas.cloneNode());
```